# GCP Console error: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Tags: google-cloud-platform, standards-compliance, cls-compliant

I tired to run the command  on GCP Shell "  systemctl status cis-level1" to check the complaince status of my GCP enviornment with CIS benchmark and got the error in screenshot
![System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.Failed to connect to bus: Host is down(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJhPY.png)

I want to regularly check my GCP enviornment with CIS policies, like in interval of 1/2 hours

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Shell is a container. Use CIS tools designed for containers and not operating systems.

However, I do not recommend checking your container every 30 minutes. Cloud Shell is a developer tool. Prolonged usage is not recommended and has a weekly Cloud Code quota is 50 hours. Only use Cloud Shell for interactive activity.

> Cloud Code is intended for interactive use only. Non-interactive
> sessions are ended automatically after one hour. Cloud Code sessions
> are capped at 12 hours, after which sessions automatically terminate.

My suggestion is to manually run your CIS tests when required, but do not schedule them.

[Cloud Code for Cloud Shell limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/shell/limitations)